# How to trigger a watch with a mocked route change in Vue/Test-utiles + vitest + vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have a simple unit test with a mocked route

```js
vi.mock('vue-router', () => {
  return {
    useRoute: vi.fn(() => ({query: 'test'})),
  };
});
```

that I change in a test

```js
it('updates query', ()=> {
  wrapper.vm.route.query = 'new value'
})
```

sadly the watcher in the component isn't triggered at all :

```js
  const route = useRoute()

  watch(route.query, () => {
    console.log('TRIGGERED');
  });
```

If I swap the mocked route by a simple object everything works as intended. I suppose the mocked router object is ignored by vue watch.

Is there a way to get around that limitation or not at all ?

Comment: The problem is the mock is not reactive, try `reactive({query: 'test'})`. Please, provide the whole code, it's unclear if wrapper.vm.route really exists

Comment: The problem is the mock is not reactive, try reactive({query: 'test'}). Please, provide the whole code, it's unclear if wrapper.vm.route really exists. Also watch(route.query requires it to be a ref but iirc it's not, should be `watch(() => route.query.some`. If that's not real code, please, provide the correct one

Comment: @EstusFlask I figured as much... I've edited my example, but route is just `const route = useRoute()`

The watch works perfectly in the real code, `useRoute` provide the proper reactivity, but the mocked version of `useRoute` apparently doesn't